# How can a Table be centred vertically with a setting, and not manually by hitting 'Enter'?

Tags: microsoft-word-2013

My selection of 'Center' below does not  effect the solution.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not related to the *table*, but to the *Page* - the same issue and solution would apply to a simple text line or block.

In the main menu, under 'Layout', you need to set the whole page to 'Vertical Alignment: Center'.
Anything that you put on the page will then be vertically centered:

[image]