# Why are the 'Layout > Align' buttons greyed and faded, and so not clickable?

Tags: microsoft-word-2013

[image]

I am trying to effect the [advice here](https://superuser.com/a/1148202/269574), but cannot as the screenshot above depicts.

> In the main menu, under 'Layout', you need to set the whole page to 'Vertical Alignment: Centered'. Anything that you put on the page will then be vertically centered.

Comment: @DavidPostill I did after your comment above, and uploaded a new screenshot: the same problem remains.

Comment: Why not just use the "Center" button in the "Paragraph" section of the Home ribbon?

Comment: @DavidPostill I did after your comment above, and uploaded a 2nd new screenshot: the same problem remains.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 For vertical alignment?

Comment: @Canada-Area51Proposal Is that a table or a text box? In either case you need to select it first.

Comment: @DavidPostill Table. I uploaded a 3rd new screenshot: the same problem remains

Comment: @Canada-Area51Proposal Did you do right click > select > table? It looks like you have selected the text not the table. It is the table you need to centre vertically.

Comment: Ahh, I though you were aiming for horizontal alignment, my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want just that table to be vertically centered, not all the content (or all content from that point onward) in the document, right-click the table, and click **Table Properties**. Under **Text wrapping**, click **Around**, and then click **Position**. Finally, under **Vertical**, set **Position** to **Center**, and **Relative** to either **Margin** or **Page**. If you don't want content before and after the table to appear on the same page as it, either insert page breaks or, when you're setting the **Position** and **Relative** properties, also set the **Distance from surrounding text** properties (**Top**, **Bottom**) to something large enough to prevent this.

Answer (score 0):

To center everything vertically (with or without text boxes, tables, etc.):

- Click the "Page Layout" tab.
- In the "Page Setup" section of that ribbon, click the little expander arrow:

[image]

- Click the "Layout" tab.
- Then choose "Center" for the "Vertical Alignment":

[image]

- For "Apply to:" choose either "Whole Document", or "This point forward" depending on your needs.
- Hit "OK".

[Image source/more info](http://www.solveyourtech.com/vertically-center-text-word-2013/)

Comment: +1. I hope that others will upvote your answer (as I did) that is as beneficient and helpful as the others. So please accept my assurance that I accepted another answer not because of any superiority between answers, but because SE allows only one acceptance that I have used to aid those with fewer reputation points.

Answer (score 0):

Make your cell high enough to see the result, then:

1. Select table
2. Right-click table
3. Table Properties > Cell > Vertical Alignment > Center